# C++でmapのイテレータを使って出力できません。

Tags: c++

mapでデータを格納し、ターミナルから入力した文字列がキーとして登録されていれば値を返すという問題をやっています。
現状のコードで取り敢えずやりたいことはできていますが、elseの中の値を出力する部分を `*it` とするとコンパイルできません。

以下のようなエラーが出ており、オペランドの型がおかしいのはわかるんですが、調べてみてもよくわかりません。

そもそも、例えばターミナルからcatと入力した場合のitには、マップAni[]の中のキーE_ani[0]のイテレータが入っているという理解であっていますか？
vectorやlistみたいには出力できないということでしょうか？それともitの使い方が間違っているのでしょうか？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’)
```

**ソースコード:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    map<string, string> Ani;
    map<string, string>::iterator it;
    string E_ani[] = {"cat", "dog", "bird","tiger"};
    Ani[E_ani[0]] = "猫";
    Ani[E_ani[1]] = "犬";
    Ani[E_ani[2]] = "鳥";
    Ani[E_ani[3]] = "トラ";
    cout << "英語で動物の名前を入力してください : 
    ";
    cin >> name;
    it = Ani.find(name);
    if (it == Ani.end())
    {
         cout << "対応するデータは登録されていません" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
         cout << "「" << Ani[name]*ここの値* << "」です。"<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージや[クラスの説明書](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/map/map/find.html)を読みましょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージは、「`std::basic_ostream<char>` (`std::cout`のこと)と`std::pair<std::string, std::string>` (`*it`のこと) に対応する `<<` がないぞ」と言っています。

`std::pair` のそれぞれの要素の表示を試してみてください。`<< it->first` とか `<< it->second` とか。